# Error de Ruta laravel 5.7 con php 7.4 al intentar exportar un documento Excel con "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite

Les comento que antes de pasar mi proyecto laravel 5.7 de php 7.1.3 a php 7.4.3 empezaron los problemas al exportar documentos en Excel usando la librería "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0" que utiliza la librería "phpexcel", eh corregido los problemas de compatibilidad entre esta librería y Php 7.4 pero al parecer ahora el problema es con mi rutas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi Ruta

```
Route::get('psicologia.ficha_psicologia.exportP', 'PsicologiaController@exportP')->name('psicologia.ficha_psicologia.exportP');
```

> Mi vista

```
<div class="row"><!--agregamos una fila-->
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"><!--agregamos columnas-->
    <h3>Listado de Alumnos Ingresantes<a href="ficha_psicologia/create"><button style="margin: 20px" class ="btn btn-primary">Nuevo</button></a><a href="{{ route('psicologia.ficha_psicologia.exportP') }}"><button style="margin: 5px" class ="btn btn-success">Exportar en excel</button></a></h3>


    <!--boton para crear un nuevo articulo y lo cual nos enciara a vista create-->
    @include('psicologia.ficha_psicologia.search')<!--incluir la vista search-->
</div>
```

> Mi controlador

```
 public function exportP(){
    
    $formulario = DB::table('formulario')->where ('estado_formulario','=','A')->get()->toArray();
    $formulario_array[] = array('nombre','e_f_p','año_ingreso','sexo','num_dni','edad','fecha_nacimiento','estado_civil','hijo','cargo_hijo','embarazo','departamento_nacimiento','provincia_nacimiento','distrito_nacimiento','direccion','idioma','telefono','telefono_apoderado','religion','seguro_salud','tipo_seguro','trabajo','ocupacion','discapacidad','tipo_discapacidad','modalidad_ingreso','sustancia_psicoactiva','CUALES SUSTANCIAS','frecuencia_sustancia_psicoactiva','violencia_psicologica', 'violencia_psicologica_cual','violencia_fisica', 'violencia_fisica_cual','violencia_sexual', 'violencia_sexual_cual','actividad_alumno','estado_animo','habito_estudio','habito_estudio_cual','rendimiento_academico','orientacion_vocacional','TEMAS A CONOCER','hobby','diagnostico_psicologico');

     foreach($formulario as $for)
    {
    $formulario_array[] = array(
    'nombre' => $for->nombre,
    'e_f_p' => $for->e_f_p,
    'año_ingreso' => $for->año_ingreso,
    'sexo' => $for->sexo,
    'num_dni' => $for->num_dni,
    'edad' => $for->edad,
    'fecha_nacimiento' => $for->fecha_nacimiento,
    'estado_civil' => $for->estado_civil,
    'hijo' => $for->hijo,
    'cargo_hijo' => $for->cargo_hijo,
    'embarazo' => $for->embarazo,
    'departamento_nacimiento' => $for->departamento_nacimiento,
    'provincia_nacimiento' => $for->provincia_nacimiento,
    'distrito_nacimiento' => $for->distrito_nacimiento,
    'direccion' => $for->direccion,
    'idioma' => $for->idioma,
    'telefono' => $for->telefono,
    'telefono_apoderado' => $for->telefono_apoderado,
    'religion' => $for->religion,
    'seguro_salud' => $for->seguro_salud,
    'tipo_seguro' => $for->tipo_seguro,
    'trabajo' => $for->trabajo,
    'ocupacion' => $for->ocupacion,
    'discapacidad' => $for->discapacidad,
    'tipo_discapacidad' => $for->tipo_discapacidad,
    'modalidad_ingreso' => $for->modalidad_ingreso,
//psicologia
'sustancia_psicoactiva' => $for->sustancia_psicoactiva,
'CUALES SUSTANCIAS' => $for->sustancia_psicoactiva_ninguno.'-'.$for->sustancia_psicoactiva_tabaco.'-'.$for->sustancia_psicoactiva_alcohol.'-'.$for->sustancia_psicoactiva_marihuana.'-'.$for->sustancia_psicoactiva_cocaina,

'frecuencia_sustancia_psicoactiva' => $for->frecuencia_sustancia_psicoactiva,
'violencia_psicologica' => $for->violencia_psicologica,
'violencia_psicologica_cual' => $for->violencia_psicologica_cual,
'violencia_fisica' => $for->violencia_fisica,
'violencia_fisica_cual' => $for->violencia_fisica_cual,
'violencia_sexual' => $for->violencia_sexual,
'violencia_sexual_cual' => $for->violencia_sexual_cual,
'actividad_alumno' => $for->actividad_alumno,
'estado_animo' => $for->estado_animo,
'habito_estudio' => $for->habito_estudio,
'habito_estudio_cual' => $for->habito_estudio_cual,
'rendimiento_academico' => $for->rendimiento_academico,
'orientacion_vocacional' => $for->orientacion_vocacional,
'TEMAS A CONOCER' => $for->conocer_tema_control_estres.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_proyecto_vida.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_liderazgo.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_habito_estudio.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_autoestima.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_manejo_emocion.'-'.$for->conocer_tema_asertividad,
'hobby' => $for->hobby,
'diagnostico_psicologico' => $for->diagnostico_psicologico
     );
    }

 Excel::create('formulario', function($excel) use ($formulario_array){
    

  $excel->setTitle('formulario');
  $excel->sheet('formulario', function($sheet) use ($formulario_array){

   $sheet->setBorder('A1:AR1', 'thin');
   $sheet->cells('A1:AR1',function($cells)
   {
    $cells->setBackground('#c7c7c7');
    $cells->setAlignment('center');
    $cells->setValignment('midle');
   });

   $sheet->fromArray($formulario_array, null, 'A1', false, false);

  });
 })->download('xlsx');
 return Redirect::to('psicologia/ficha_psicologia');
}
```

> Antes de migrar de versión de php todo funcionaba con normalidad, y ahora ya no puedo regresar a la versión anterior porque tengo algunas dependencias que funcionan con la actual

Comment: ya intentaste con php artisan route:cache???

Comment: Si, al parecer las ruta ya no se llaman de esa manera en php 7.4, eh estado intentando de todo y nada